# Why are my quill pedal cages "wobbling"?

Tags: road-bike, repair, parts, pedals, vintage

The plates and connectors on my old quill pedals "move around" in relation to the pedal axle itself: In the photo below, I'm pushing the pedals to opposite sides to show how the pedal cage "distorts". The fact that the plates and these connectors are loose in this way causes them to "wobble" while riding, which means not only that the pedals move around a little bit while riding but— more importantly— they make horribly annoying metallic rattling/squeaking sounds when riding.

[image: Quill pedal with loose connectors, highlighted in red]

Comment: So the frame distorts like a parallelogram?  Where is the freedom of movement coming from?   The bearings are okay, its the outer part only with the problem?

Comment: So the cage isn't part of the pedal body. Can that endcap/dustcap at the left-hand side be tightened up? What holds the right-hand side of the cage in place? Can that be tightened?

Comment: Based on this post and the one you made before, I think you're spending way too much time on a pair of crappy pedals. Just because something's old, doesn't mean it's worth restoring. If the pedal cage is no longer attached securely to the body (assuming it was ever attached securely in the first place) then the only solution is to weld it. And that's only possible if they're the same metal - I can't be sure, but the cage looks like steel and the body like aluminum.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak: Why don't you find me some 14*1.25mm threaded pedals and send them to me, then? I'd love you forever for saving me so much time. Alternatively, you can come by (to Central Europe) and tap out my crank like everyone else recommends me to do although it would probably cost €300+ here.

Comment: If the end plates are moving in respect to the axle housing then they are not adequately fastened at the ends.  This may be due to wear, or it may simply mean that the caps on each end need to be tightened.

Comment: @errantlinguist - OK, your motivation makes more sense now. (Although, €300 just to re-tap the cranks seems pretty high.)

Comment: @MikeBaranczak would silver-soldering work?  Or brazing the two dissimilar metals?  Probably not since one is aluminium which is always hard.    I'd go with drill and retapping the cranks for 9/16"

Comment: @MikeBaranczak: There are some practical advantages to living where labor costs are not astronomical...

Answer (score -1):

it looks to me like the cage part of the pedal is pressed together you may be able to remove the pedal and pound the end of the cage part back into the frame of the pedal thee type of connections are held together by distortion of the metal ie widening of the end of the piece to be held by widening by pressure like a rivet so possibly u could re hammer them together

Comment: Welcome! I think I know where you're headed with your answer, but it's hard to tell. Some punctuation and capitalization would make your answer much more readable.